# Double subscript problem

Tags: equations, subscripts

The code

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\FAggregate}{F}

\begin{equation}
q_k'(e) = \FAggregate\limits_{a \in R}_a (q_k(S(a)))
\end{equation}
```

causes a problem with an additional `_a`. 
What I want is the `a` to show in the subscript position as shown in the following picture:

[image: desired output]

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 9):

I suggest to add the subscript as an argument to `\FAggregate`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\FAggregate}[1][]{\operatorname*{F_\mathnormal{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
q_k'(e) = \FAggregate[a]_{a \in R} (q_k(S(a)))
\ne\FAggregate_{a \in R} (q_k(S(a)))
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If the subscript is mandatory, then define

```
\newcommand{\FAggregate}[1]{\operatorname*{F_\mathnormal{#1}}}
```

and use it as

```
\FAggregate{a}_{a \in R}
```

Note that `\limits` is not necessary in display style.

[image]

Comment: You may want to change `F_\mathnormal{#1}}` to `F_{\!\mathnormal{#1}}}` to mitigate the visual "hole" that would otherwise arise because the lower-right "zone" of the letter "F" is empty.

Comment: @Mico This might be a valuable addition in this particular case, due to the shape of the letter.